# How to extract the pubhtml ID in google sheet using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the webpage link of my google sheet using Apps Script. When you go to the File>Publish to the web>publish, you will see a weblink there. I want to get that link via apps script. Please help.

Comment: @Tanaike you are right. Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the URL like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

`File>Publish to the web>publish` can be run for the Google Docs. This URL could been retrieved with `publishedLink` of Drive API v2 before. But in the current stage, unfortunately, this cannot be used for both Drive API v2 and v3. So as a workaround, I would like to propose to use file ID.

By the way, `2PACX-###` of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` is not the file ID. Also please be careful this.

#### Sample script:

In this case, as a test case, the URL of published Spreadsheet is retrieved.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace("edit", "pubhtml"); // or replace("edit", "pub");
  Logger.log(url)
}
```

#### Note:

- At above script, when the Spreadsheet is not published to web, when you access to the URL, the Spreadsheet is not shown. Please be careful this.
- For example, if you want to retrieve the URL of Google Document, you can use the following script. Unfortunately, at Google Document, `getUrl()` returns `https://docs.google.com/open?id=###`. So above script cannot be used.

  ```
  function myFunction() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + doc.getId() + "/pub";
    Logger.log(url)
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [V2 to v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference)
- [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getUrl())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

If [you can enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), you can also use the following script.

#### Pattern 1:

When you use the container-bound script of Google Docs, you can use this.

```
var url = Drive.Files.get((DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() || SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()).getId()).alternateLink.replace(/\/edit.+/, "/pub");
Logger.log(url);
```

#### Pattern 2:

When you have the file ID of Google Docs, you can use this.

```
var url = Drive.Files.get(fileId).alternateLink.replace(/\/edit.+/, "/pub");
Logger.log(url);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now @Tanaike. However, I have 800+ google sheets inside my google drive. How can I publish to web all of these templates and get the weblink id?

Comment: Sure @tanaike. I understand. Thank you so much for your help. I'll just post another question regarding my new issue. I appreciate your help

Comment: @architect_mosby017 Thank you for replying and your response. I will check it. By the way, I had understood your this question was resolved. But if my answer for your this question is not resolved your issue, please tell me. I have to modify it. How about this?

Comment: Apologies about that. =) It's all good now. Thanks again for your help. I already posted a new one regarding my other concern.

Comment: @architect_mosby017 Thank you for your response. I checked it. I noticed that it has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: Thanks again @Tanaike. Do you also have thoughts on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715849/spreadsheet-flush-is-not-working-properly-on-my-google-apps-script

Comment: @architect_mosby017 Thank you for replying. When I saw it, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.