# How can we get the embed URL using google app script for a Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, url, embedding

I am able to publish the sheet but unable to get its published URL to render it as a html page. Do we have a way to get the embed URL of the google sheet via google app scripts? I can't do it manually by copying the URL by opening the Google spread sheet every time.

Comment: If I could correctly understand your question, I thought that these threads might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50997579 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58635613 If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.